# How do I create a list of tuples that contains values that change?

Tags: python

Relatively new to Python here. I feel like this is a question that has a simple answer but I cannot seem to figure it out. Basically, I am trying to create a list of tuples to present my output. Here's the code so far:

```
class MarblesBoard:
    
    def __init__(self, sequence):
        self.sequence = []
        for i in range(len(sequence)):
            self.sequence.append(sequence[i])
            
    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(map(str, self.sequence))
    
    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join(map(str, self.sequence))
        
    def switch(self):
        second = self.sequence[1]
        self.sequence[1] = self.sequence[0]
        self.sequence[0] = second
        
    def rotate(self):
        first = self.sequence.pop(0)
        self.sequence.append(first)
        
    def is_solved(self):
        for i in range(len(self.sequence)):
            if i != self.sequence[i]:
                return False
        return True



class Solver:
    
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        
    def solve(self):
        
        print(("start", self.board))

        while not self.board.is_solved():
            if self.board.sequence[0] > self.board.sequence[1]:
                self.board.rotate()
                print(('rotate', self.board))
            else:
                self.board.switch()
                print(('switch', self.board))
```

Running the above code gives me:

```
('start', 1 3 0 2)
('switch', 3 1 0 2)
('rotate', 1 0 2 3)
('rotate', 0 2 3 1)
('switch', 2 0 3 1)
('rotate', 0 3 1 2)
('switch', 3 0 1 2)
('rotate', 0 1 2 3)
```

But instead of this output, I want to see:

```
[('start', 1 3 0 2),
 ('rotate', 3 1 0 2),
 ('rotate', 1 0 2 3),
 ('rotate', 0 2 3 1),
 ('switch', 2 0 3 1),
 ('rotate', 0 3 1 2),
 ('rotate', 3 0 1 2),
 ('rotate', 0 1 2 3)]
```

I've tried creating a list and appending tuples to it within the if-else statements too:

```
class Solver:
    
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        
    def solve(self):
        
        status = []
        status.append(("start", self.board))

        while not self.board.is_solved():
            if self.board.sequence[0] > self.board.sequence[1]:
                self.board.rotate()
                status.append(("rotated", self.board))
            else:
                self.board.switch()
                status.append(("switch", self.board))

        return status
```

But that gives me results similar to:

```
[('start', 0 1 2 3),
 ('rotate', 0 1 2 3),
 ('rotate', 0 1 2 3),
 ('rotate', 0 1 2 3),
 ('switch', 0 1 2 3),
 ('rotate', 0 1 2 3),
 ('rotate', 0 1 2 3),
 ('rotate', 0 1 2 3)]
```

I have a suspicion that this has something to do with the immutability of tuples, but am not sure. How can I get a list of tuples in this situation?

Comment: Please update your question with the code which creates a list. There will be a simple modification to save copies in the tuples.

Comment: Ok, so what is `board` that you pass into `Solver`?

Comment: @quamrana a sequence of numbers, in this case (1,3,0,2). `Solver` then rotates/switches the numbers around and puts them in numerical order.

Comment: Ok, I meant: Please update your question with the code of `Board`

Comment: @quamrana updated, sorry about the confusion!

Comment: The suggested output doesn't align with the coding strategy. If the initial values are 1,3,0,2 then the first activity would be a 'switch' and not a 'rotate'. Also, do you realise that this is not an algorithm for solving this problem. Try changing some of the values and/or change the size of the list then sit back and relax as your code goes into an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see. You just need to make a string of `board`.

```py
    status.append(("rotated", str(self.board))
```

etc ...

Comment: That would give me the numbers like '1 3 0 2', is there a way to remove the quotation marks?

Comment: No. That would be invalid syntax. But when do you want to print them?

Comment: Got it. I just have `print(status)` after the while loop. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm implemented here will only work for certain initial values (such as the ones shown in the original question). Other values are likely to trigger an infinite loop. However, the question is about the output format. So:

```
class MarblesBoard:
    def __init__(self, sequence):
        self.sequence = sequence.copy()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(map(str, self.sequence))
        
    def switch(self):
        self.sequence[1], self.sequence[0] = self.sequence[0], self.sequence[1]
        
    def rotate(self):
        self.sequence.append(self.sequence.pop(0))
        
    def is_solved(self):
        return sorted(self.sequence) == self.sequence



class Solver:
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        
    def solve(self):
        activities = [("start", MarblesBoard(self.board.sequence))]

        while not self.board.is_solved():
            if self.board.sequence[0] > self.board.sequence[1]:
                self.board.rotate()
                activities.append(('rotate', MarblesBoard(self.board.sequence)))
            else:
                self.board.switch()
                activities.append(('switch', MarblesBoard(self.board.sequence)))
        return activities

print(Solver(MarblesBoard([1,3,0,2])).solve())
```

**Output:**

```
[('start', 1 3 0 2), ('switch', 3 1 0 2), ('rotate', 1 0 2 3), ('rotate', 0 2 3 1), ('switch', 2 0 3 1), ('rotate', 0 3 1 2), ('switch', 3 0 1 2), ('rotate', 0 1 2 3)]
```